# How to build a scalable Reporting Solution with data from a web service?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-replication

I have a WCF web service that currently is recording a record to SQL Server 2005 roughly every second throughout they day. Our business reporting team runs SELECT queries against this database in live.
I want to rethink this solution, so that the business reports are not querying our table directly. This is to prevent locking or other performance hits to my WCF web service.
So I am thinking about using another database to hold the reporting data, which will be a transformed version of the source record.

Can anyone point me towards the Microsoft technologies that will allow the WCF service to maintain 100% availability, and the maximum throughput of records possible - so no performance hits.

Answer (score 0):

Without having tried this myself, I would recommend you to take a look at [Snapshot Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb.aspx). From what I have read this sounds like what you might need.